# Itinerary for the south of India

Tags: planning, india, itineraries

I'm planning a trip to the south of the India and Sri Lanka. For India I have about 25 days starting and ending at Mumbai and taking some flights and night trains. This is the route:

```
24J: Arrive to Mumbai (4:30) - Fligh to Bangalore (10:45) - Visit Bangalore 
25J: Visit de Bangalore - Afternoon train to Mysore (15:00-17:30)
26J: Mysore 
27J: Mysore - Ooty 
28J: Ooty - Pollachi 
29J: Pollachi (Parambikulam Tiger Reserve) 
30J: Pollachi (Parambikulam Tiger Reserve) 
31J: Bus to Madurai - Flight from Madurai to Colombo (16:30) 
... Itinerary in Sri Lanka
14A: Flight Colombo-Madurai (13:50) 
15A: Madurai 
16A: Madurai - Night train to Varkala (23:15-8:01) 
17A: Varkala 
18A: Varkala - Train to Trivandrum 
19A: Trivandrum 
20A: Trivandrum - Train to Alleppey 
21A: Alleppey 
22A: Alleppey (night at Backwaters) 
23A: Alleppey - Kochi 
24A: Kochi 
25A: Kochi - Flight to Trichy (16:00) 
26A: Trichy - Thanjavur 
27A: Thanjavur – Dharasuram-Kambakonam-Gangakonda-Traquebar 
28A: Traquebar – Pondicherry – Mahalipuram 
29A: Mahalipuram (visit to Kanchipuram) 
30A: Train to Chennai - Flight Chennai to Goa (12:20) 
31A: Anjuna or Palolem beach
01S: Anjuna or Palolem beach
02S: Anjuna o Palolem beach – Flight from Goa to Mumbai (18:35) - Night at airport
03S: Flight to home (5:55).
```

Is this itinerary realistic? Should I change something? Some of the flights (specially those that go to / from Sri Lanka) cannot be moved, others may be moved by one or two days before / after. Also I don't have any problem by removing an area or changing part of the trip if any India expert advice me to do change it.

Comment: I notice you dont have the most visited areas in Kerala - Thekkady reserve and Munnar lake which are 3 hours from Kochi (in between Alleppey and Kochi) on your itinerary. Are you avoiding "touristy" places ?

Comment: Not really, the "real problem" is the flight to Sri Lanka. I cannot move these dates and I don't know how to fit Thekkady and Munnar

Comment: Since you are spending very few days in places like Kochi (from where you can visit Guruvayur, Munnar, Thekkady etc), Chennai (Kumbakonam, Trichy), I would suggest you check out some pics from Picasa or elsewhere to filter out places you may not like / similar places.  You will need to take enough rest at each place, to be able to enjoy the place better.  So, would suggest you to cut down on the number of places and instead spend more time in places you feel you will like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't really have an objective answer, as the answer to quite an extent depends on an individual's desires and preferences. That said, as I'm sure you realise yourself, your trip is quite action packed. It's definitely *possible*, but I think that were I to follow your itinerary, I would need a holiday after coming home.

To compare, I just spent about 20 days in India, visiting Mumbai, Calcutta, Chennai and a few small towns within fairly close proximity of Chennai (Mamallapuram, Pondicherry and Tiruvannamalai).
The smaller towns were quite easily visited staying two nights, but the larger ones easily warranted longer stays, particularly Mumbai.

You've got several larger towns on your list. To me it would make sense to stay there a little bit longer.
That said, I suspect you have no interest in seeing Mumbai, as you're not really staying there at all. However, if you haven't been there before, I'd highly recommend it.

Comment: Yes, you are right: my interest in Mumbai is just that it is the city we arrive :) You are the first person that has talked positively about Mumbai and that's the reason to avoid it. But what you say makes sense, may be there is too action ;)

Comment: The first? Wow. I *really* enjoyed it. There's plenty to see and do. And, who knows, when strolling the streets, you might be scouted for the next major Bollywood movie :)